# Non-clustered index with WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, where-clause

I have a large table (around 100 million rows). I am trying to optimize searches.  Most of my searches use two columns: `bar nvarchar(64)` and `foo nvarchar(64)`.

I am only interested in `foo` when:

```
foo = 'string01'
OR
foo = 'string02'
OR
foo IS NULL
```

I was thinking on creating the following non clustered index:

```
CREATE INDEX ixbar 
ON myTable (bar) 
INCLUDE (foo) 
WHERE foo IN ('string01', 'string02') OR foo IS NULL
```

But the `OR` statement is not allowed in a `WHERE` clause for an index. This makes me think that probably I am not approaching this correctly.

I would appreciate any suggestion on the most efficient way of doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: Might be worth a try: `WHERE ISNULL(foo, 'string01') IN ('string01, 'string02')`

Comment: Create two different indexes.

Comment: You'd be better posting this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - this is a code site, they are a DBA site and have a lot more specialised expertise.

Comment: @Tyron78, I am not sure I understand the statement.

Comment: As an optimisation technique, `UNION ALL` often performs better than `OR`.

Comment: @CriticalError.  OK, that is an idea. Thanks.

Comment: @DaleK, you are right, I'll do that.

Comment: @Wilmar You wrote you only want string01, string02 or NULL and this "or" didn't work in the index. Therefore I wrote `ISNULL(foo, 'string01')` - so it handles foo with string01 or string02, since NULL is interpreted as string01 as well

Comment: Just creating indexes might not solve the problem. In order for SQL Server to use an index, this index is preferable to have high selectivity. I'm telling this because I see 'string01' and 'string02' in a table with around 100 million rows. Search online for Computing Index Selectivity.

Comment: Hi @shadow. I agree, indexes are just one step towards trying to make it better.  It helped however, a query that was taking around 6 hours to complete (yes, 6 hours) after the indexes is taking around 2 hours. Still too long but it is a 66% improvement. Now I am trying to change my query to make it more efficient.  I am not too familiar with Windows and Partitions but I believe that may help. I am studying! Thanks for commenting!